# change column type to integer rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have run a migration when trying  to change on heroku table column from string to integer:
This is my migration:

```
class ChangePriceTypeInItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :items, :price, :integer
  end
end
```

And this is my error:
What do I do?

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "price" cannot be cast automatically to type integer
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING price::integer".
: ALTER TABLE "items" ALTER COLUMN "price" TYPE integer
```

Comment: What type was it previously? Some column types cannot be automatically cast to `:integer` because of the existing data.

Answer (score 11):

The other answers are correct, yet you can also use the `:using` keyword:

```
change_column :items, :price, :integer, using: 'price::integer'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure the data in the string column can be converted to integer then go ahead with this change to your migration:

```
change_column :items, :price, 'integer USING CAST(price AS integer)'
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

```
 change_column :table_name, :column_name, 'integer USING CAST(column_name AS integer)'
```

For more details visit this site [how-to-change-columns-from-string-to-integer](http://makandracards.com/makandra/18691-postgresql-vs-rails-migration-how-to-change-columns-from-string-to-integer)

Answer (score 1):

```rb
class ChangePriceTypeInItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  safety_assured

  def change
    # Take the back-up of your data first
    Item.update_all(price: nil)
    change_column :items, :price, :integer, using: 'price::integer'
  end
end
```